# unit testing framework for C without installation?

Tags: c, unit-testing, frameworks, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse CDT for a C project.

I found out most of the frameworks require installation to use.

I need one framework that doesn't require installation and just need to include the 
.h files or/and .c files so that I can use the framework anywhere.

The MinUnit is very cool but it's tool simple. I can use the MinUnit  If there's a plugin like Junit to generate the test function stubs for me.

Is there any Eclipse CDT plugin to generate test function stubs like Junit did?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about CUnit? When I used it - I just added the files as a sub-project to my development tree.

Comment: sorry. I didn't look at it carefully, but I don't know know the make-tests.sh doesn't work. I mean it cannot generate  "SUITE_ADD_TEST " part. anything relate to $FILES cannot be generate. Do you know why? Also, what does this mean "  

if test $# -eq 0 ; then FILES=*.c ; else FILES=$* ; fi

"

Comment: I see why because the .c files mush have lines start with void Test